# How to use python to get pieces of info in a string

Tags: python, string, pandas

I'm new to python, and now I need to use it to work with some data in a txt file.

Here is a sample data, where after each `'&'`, is a new index:

```
uid=aaa&sid=bbb&bid=ccc&cid=ddd&pid=eee&ver=fff...
uid=aaa2&sid=bbb2&bid=ccc2&cid=ddd2&pid=eee2&ver=fff2...
...
```

The end result is to have a DataFrame (with pandas) with `columns=['uid', 'sid', 'bid', 'cid', 'pid', 'ver'...]` and the content of `uid` as index.

My idea is: to strip out `aaa`, `bbb`, and `ccc`, etc. from the string, and insert them into the dataframe.

I've tried:

```
st1 = gif?uid=aaa&sid=bbb&bid=ccc&cid=ddd&pid=eee&ver=fff......HTTPasfawfaw

(st1 is the original string)

st2 = st1.split("gif?")[1].split("HTTP")[0]

st3 = st2.split('&')
```

My question is:

1. how can I only take the string after the `=` out and put them in Dataframe?
2. I need to deal with huge data files, is there a better way to do this with less time and takes less memory?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: About 1: just split the string. If my understanding of your worflow is right, you get at one point strings like `"uid=aaa"`. If so, split each on `'='`, and access the element at index `1`.

Comment: @Rightleg thank you, I've tried this, and this will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a URL querystring. You should use the `urllib` module in the standard library to parse it.

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs  # python3
from urlparse import parse_qs # python2

parse_qs('uid=aaa2&sid=bbb2&bid=ccc2&cid=ddd2&pid=eee2&ver=fff2')
```

Output:

```
{'bid': ['ccc2'],
 'cid': ['ddd2'],
 'pid': ['eee2'],
 'sid': ['bbb2'],
 'uid': ['aaa2'],
 'ver': ['fff2']}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But I'm more into how to process multiple lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` to create a `list` of all the columns and values and then use it to create your `dataframe`, for example:

```
import re
st = 'uid=aaa&sid=bbb&bid=ccc&cid=ddd&pid=eee&ver=fffuid=aaa2&sid=bbb2&bid=ccc2&cid=ddd2&pid=eee2&ver=fff2'
myData = re.findall(r'(\wid)=(\w+)', st)
prit myData
```

output:

```
[('uid', 'aaa'), ('sid', 'bbb'), ('bid', 'ccc'), ('cid', 'ddd'), ('pid', 'eee'), ('uid', 'aaa2'), ('sid', 'bbb2'), ('bid', 'ccc2'), ('cid', 'ddd2'), ('pid', 'eee2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txt = open('test.txt').read()

pd.DataFrame(
    [dict([kv.split('=') for kv in l.split('&')]) for l in txt.split('\n')]
)

    bid   cid   pid   sid   uid   ver
0   ccc   ddd   eee   bbb   aaa   fff
1  ccc2  ddd2  eee2  bbb2  aaa2  fff2
```